# use preg_split to split chords and words

Tags: php, parsing, preg-split

I'm working on a little piece of code playing handling song tabs, but i'm stuck on a problem.

I need to parse each song tab line and to split it to get chunks of *chords* on the one hand, and *words* in the other.

Each chunk would be like :

```
$line_chunk = array(
    0 => //part of line containing one or several chords
    1 => //part of line containing words
);
```

They should stay "grouped".  I mean by this that it should split only when the function reaches the "limit" between chords and words.

I guess I should use **preg_split** to achieve this.  I made some tests, but I've been only able to split on chords, not "groups" of chords:

```
$line_chunks = preg_split('/(\[[^]]*\])/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Those examples shows you what I would like to get :

on a line containing no chords :

```
$input = '{intro}';

$results = array(
    array(
        0 => null,
        1 => '{intro}
    )
);
```

on a line containing only chords :

```
$input = '[C#] [Fm] [C#] [Fm] [C#] [Fm]';

$results = array(
    array(
        0 => '[C#] [Fm] [C#] [Fm] [C#] [Fm]',
        1 => null
    )
);
```

on a line containing both :

```
$input = '[C#]I’m looking for [Fm]you [G#]';

$results = array(
    array(
        0 => '[C#]',
        1 => 'I’m looking for'
    ),
    array(
        0 => '[Fm]',
        1 => 'you '
    ),
    array(
        0 => '[G#]',
        1 => null
    ),
);
```

Any ideas of how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_split` isn't the way to go. Most of the time, when you have a complicated split task to achieve, it's more easy to try to match what you are interested by instead of trying to split with a *not easy to define* separator.

A `preg_match_all` approach:

```
$pattern = '~ \h*
(?|        # open a "branch reset group"
    ( \[ [^]]+ ] (?: \h* \[ [^]]+ ] )*+ ) # one or more chords in capture group 1
    \h*
    ( [^[\n]* (?<=\S) )  # eventual lyrics (group 2)
  |                      # OR
    ()                   # no chords (group 1)
    ( [^[\n]* [^\s[] )   # lyrics (group 2)
)          # close the "branch reset group"
~x';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $result = array_map(function($i) { return [$i[1], $i[2]]; }, $matches);
    print_r($result);
}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI6gU8/1)

*A branch reset group preserves the same group numbering for each branch.*

Note: feel free to add:

```
if (empty($i[1])) $i[1] = null;    
if (empty($i[2])) $i[2] = null;
```

in the map function if you want to obtain null items instead of empty items.

Note2: if you work line by line, you can remove the `\n` from the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with PHP `explode`:

```
/*
 * Process data
 */
$input = '[C#]I’m looking for [Fm]you [G#]';
$parts = explode("[", $input);
$results = array();

foreach ($parts as $item)
{
    $pieces = explode("]", $item);

    if (count($pieces) < 2)
    {
        $arrayitem = array( "Chord" => $pieces[0],
                            "Lyric" => "");
    }
    else
    {
        $arrayitem = array( "Chord" => $pieces[0],
                            "Lyric" => $pieces[1]);
    }

    $results[] = $arrayitem;
}

/*
 * Echo results
 */
foreach ($results as $str)
{
    echo "Chord: " . $str["Chord"];
    echo "Lyric: " . $str["Lyric"];
}
```

Boudaries are not tested in the code, as well as remaining whitespaces, but it is a base to work on.